# AC_ARG_ENABLE in an m4_foreach_w loop: no help string

Tags: autoconf, m4

I wish to generate a lot of `--enable-*/--disable-*` options by something like:

```
COMPONENTS([a b c], [yes])
```

where the second argument is the default value of the automatic `enable_*` variable. My first attempt was to write an `AC_ARG_ENABLE(...)` within an `m4_foreach_w`, but so far, I'm only getting the first component to appear in the `./configure --help` output.

If I add hand-written `AC_ARG_ENABLE`s, they work as usual.

Regardless, the `--enable-*/--disable-*` options work as they should, just the help text is missing.

Here's the full code to reproduce the problem:

```
AC_INIT([foo], 1.0)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])

AC_DEFUN([COMPONENTS],
[
    m4_foreach_w([component], [$1], [
        AS_ECHO(["Processing [component] component with default enable=$2"])
        AC_ARG_ENABLE([component],
            [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-[]component], [component] component)],
            ,
            [enable_[]AS_TR_SH([component])=$2]
        )
    ])
    AC_ARG_ENABLE([x],
        [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-[]x], [component x])],
        ,
        [enable_[]AS_TR_SH([x])=$2]
    )
    AC_ARG_ENABLE([y],
        [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-[]y], [component y])],
        ,
        [enable_[]AS_TR_SH([y])=$2]
    )
])

COMPONENTS([a b c], [yes])

for var in a b c x y; do
    echo -n "\$enable_$var="
    eval echo "\$enable_$var"
done
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

And an empty `Makefile.am`. To verify that the options work:

```
$ ./configure --disable-a --disable-b --disable-d --disable-x
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-d
...
Processing component a with default enable=yes
Processing component b with default enable=yes
Processing component c with default enable=yes
$enable_a=no
$enable_b=no
$enable_c=yes
$enable_x=no
$enable_y=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I poked around in autoconf sources, I figured out this has to do with the `m4_divert_once` call in the implementation of `AC_ARG_ENABLE`:

```
# AC_ARG_ENABLE(FEATURE, HELP-STRING, [ACTION-IF-TRUE], [ACTION-IF-FALSE])
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC_DEFUN([AC_ARG_ENABLE],
[AC_PROVIDE_IFELSE([AC_PRESERVE_HELP_ORDER],
[],
[m4_divert_once([HELP_ENABLE], [[
Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]]])])dnl
m4_divert_once([HELP_ENABLE], [$2])dnl
_AC_ENABLE_IF([enable], [$1], [$3], [$4])dnl
])# AC_ARG_ENABLE

# m4_divert_once(DIVERSION-NAME, CONTENT)
# ---------------------------------------
# Output CONTENT into DIVERSION-NAME once, if not already there.
# An end of line is appended for free to CONTENT.
m4_define([m4_divert_once],
[m4_expand_once([m4_divert_text([$1], [$2])])])
```

I'm guessing that the `HELP-STRING` argument is remembered in it's unexpanded form, so it is added just once for all components. Manually expanding the `AC_HELP_STRING` does what I want:

```
AC_DEFUN([COMPONENTS],
[
    m4_foreach_w([comp], [$1], [
        AS_ECHO(["Processing component 'comp' with default enable=$2"])
        AC_ARG_ENABLE([comp],
            m4_expand([AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-comp], enable component comp)]),
            ,
            [enable_[]AS_TR_SH([comp])=$2]
        )
    ])
])

COMPONENTS([a b c x y], [yes])
```

I couldn't find a way to properly quote `components` so that it appears as a string, after being used as the loop variable in `m4_foreach_w`, so I just renamed it to spare me the trouble.